# Router can not find nested Route components v6

Tags: javascript, react-router, react-router-dom

I'm using react-router v6 and I have such simple App component.

```js
type RouteType = {
  path: string;
  element: any;
}

function App() {
  const [user] = useAuthState(auth);

  const USER_ROUTES: RouteType[] = user ? [
    { path: '/signin', element: <Login /> },
    { path: '/signup', element: <Signup /> },
  ] : [
    { path: '/games', element: <Games /> },
    { path: '/tournaments', element: <Tournaments /> },
    { path: '/mymatches', element: <MyMatches /> },
  ];

  const PUBLIC_ROUTES: RouteType[] = [
    { path: '*', element: <NotFound /> },
    { path: '/', element: <Home /> },
  ];

  return (
    <>
      <Header />
      <Routes>
        {[...USER_ROUTES, ...PUBLIC_ROUTES].map(
          ({ path, element }, i) => <Route key={i} path={path} element={element} />,
        )}
      </Routes>
    </>
  );
}
```

But independently on `user` value it always renders `*` route (NotFound). How can I rewrite this piece of code with such concept but without error?

Thanks.

Comment: What is the error? What routes are nested? If `user` is truthy then shouldn't the `USER_ROUTES` return the non-signin/signup routes?

Comment: When `user === undefined` we will have 4 routes rendered. But when I'm changing location (e.g. to `/signin`) nothing happens. It always renders the NotFound route. There is no any error, just unexpected behaviour.

Comment: When `user === undefined` the `"/signin"` route isn't rendered, so having the `NotFound` component render makes sense as far as I can see.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I can see you've inverted the logic for your user routes. When `user` is truthy you render the signin/signup routes instead of the routes an "authentictated" user should be able to access.

When `user` is falsey `"/games"`, `"/tournaments"`, and `"/mymatches"` is returned for user routes. If you attempt to navigate to `"/signin"` the `"*"` path catches it and renders `NotFound` component since no route for `"/signin"` is currently rendered.

Swap the routes returned for `USER_ROUTES` when `user` is truthy.

```js
function App() {
  const [user] = useAuthState(auth);

  const USER_ROUTES: RouteType[] = user ? [
    // truthy user, render user routes
    { path: '/games', element: <Games /> },
    { path: '/tournaments', element: <Tournaments /> },
    { path: '/mymatches', element: <MyMatches /> },
  ] : [
    // falsey user, render signin/signup routes to authenticate
    { path: '/signin', element: <Login /> },
    { path: '/signup', element: <Signup /> },
  ];

  const PUBLIC_ROUTES: RouteType[] = [
    { path: '*', element: <NotFound /> },
    { path: '/', element: <Home /> },
  ];

  return (
    <>
      <Header />
      <Routes>
        {[...USER_ROUTES, ...PUBLIC_ROUTES].map(({ path, element }) => (
          <Route key={path} path={path} element={element} />
        ))}
      </Routes>
    </>
  );
}
```

Comment: It's a misstype that I inverted the condition for authenticated routes. The real problem is that any of these route does not match with location except of `NotFound`. I will give you a codesandbox in a few minutes.

Comment: @entithat I see. Yes, a *running* codesandbox would be useful here.

Comment: It is sooo strange. I have created a codesandbox and it works there. https://codesandbox.io/s/react-17-miqcxu. Oh I got it...........

Comment: @entithat I don't see any links to navigate to these routes... if you are manually entering URLs in the address bar these count as page loads and your app is remounted, any state is reset.